# how to prevent automatic download from idm .mp4

Tags: html, dropbox, mp4, dropbox-api, idm

I have a website for streaming

I use this

```
<div>
  <div style="position:relative;padding-top:56.25%;">
    <iframe src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/j2j9ua0m1w3hqco/A%20Confused%20Instrument%20_%20Dameon%20Makes%20Music%20%2315.mp4?raw=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen 
      style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

how to stop auto download automatically?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJCFs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't open a video file in an `<iframe>` (it expects to process HTML code). 
Use the `<video>` tag to decode/display the video data.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div>
  <div style="position:relative;padding-top:56.25%;">
    <video controls style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;">
      <source src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/j2j9ua0m1w3hqco/A%20Confused%20Instrument%20_%20Dameon%20Makes%20Music%20%2315.mp4?raw=1" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```